# Error raised while trying to install PyV8 for Python 3.4

Tags: windows, python-3.x, installation, pyv8

I tried to install PyV8 for Python 3.4, but an error was raised. I googled for solutions, but I couldn't find a way to install PyV8 for Python 3.4 on Windows.

My system:
Windows 10 home
Python 3.4 (64bit)
Eclipse Neon 2

I tried using PIP:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\Scripts>pip install pyv8
Downloading/unpacking pyv8
  Downloading PyV8-0.5.zip
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Sebastian Weidemann\pyv8\setup.py) egg_info for package pyv8
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Sebastian Weidemann\pyv8\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        include_dirs += os.environ["INCLUDE"].split(';')
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\os.py", line 651, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key) from None
    KeyError: 'INCLUDE'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Sebastian Weidemann\pyv8\setup.py", line 17, in <module>

    include_dirs += os.environ["INCLUDE"].split(';')

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\os.py", line 651, in __getitem__

    raise KeyError(key) from None

KeyError: 'INCLUDE'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_ME\pyv8
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\ME\pip\pip.log

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\Scripts>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you find any alternative for pyv8.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's a problem of compatibility. If you look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyV8 you will see the download list https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyv8/downloads which are compatible only with Python 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7. So it seems that you can't use PyV8 together with Python 3. At least I couldn't after trying for several hours.

Comment: Even 2.7 displays this error (just FYI; found this page on google).